# Select Highest value against each record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and the problem I am having is that I have the value for alot assets in a table. 
I need to get the highest speed for each asset in that table.

I have tried searching google but I found the `MAX()` function of SQL.

I don't need the `MAX()` because that will only give me one record with the highest value. I need the highest for each asset:

e.g.

iAssetId    fSpeedKPH

**1     78**

5   77

**5 80**

8   74

8   81

8   88

**8 111**

24  71

24  78

24  79

24  79

24  82

24  84

24  90

24  91

**24    92**

I have highlighted the highest row for each asset i.e. AssetId = 1, 5, 24 and 8

These are the rows I need to select.

**What is the most efficient way?**

**Do I have to loop through this result-set returned by the SQL I have written?**

**EDIT:**

**My SQL:**

```
DECLARE @dateMinusDay datetime = DateAdd(dd, -1, GetDate())

select vm.iAssetId, max(vm.fSpeedKPH), vm.dtUTCDateTime, ge.sGeofenceName  from VehicleMonitoringLog vm
inner join Geofences ge on ge.iGeofenceId = vm.iGeofenceId

where vm.iGeofenceId != 1 AND vm.fSpeedKPH > 70 AND (vm.dtUTCDateTime > @dateMinusDay AND vm.dtUTCDateTime < GETDATE())

group by
vm.iAssetId,vm.fSpeedKPH, vm.dtUTCDateTime, ge.sGeofenceName
```

Comment: Looks like someone has asked almost the same question here:
[SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: Well, you added to many columns to your select, and are also grouping speed, that doesn't make sense in this case. Do you need all the other columns?

Comment: Yes. I need the columns.

Comment: Remove vm.fSpeedKPH from the GROUP BY.

Comment: Then why didn't you add them in the question when you asked it?

Comment: I didn't know that the number of columns I need was related to selecting the highest record against each asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT iAssetId, fSpeedKPH
FROM (
SELECT iAssetId, fSpeedKPH
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY iAssetId ORDER BY fSpeedKPH DESC) AS RN
FROM Table_Name )Sub
WHERE RN = 1
```

**UPDATE**

```
DECLARE @dateMinusDay datetime = DateAdd(dd, -1, GetDate())

SELECT Q.iAssetId, Q.dtUTCDateTime, Q.sGeofenceName
FROM (
select vm.iAssetId
      , vm.dtUTCDateTime
      , ge.sGeofenceName  
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vm.iAssetId ORDER BY vm.fSpeedKPH DESC) AS RN
from VehicleMonitoringLog vm inner join Geofences ge 
on ge.iGeofenceId = vm.iGeofenceId
where vm.iGeofenceId != 1 AND vm.fSpeedKPH > 70 
AND (vm.dtUTCDateTime > @dateMinusDay   --<-- Instead of variable you can use GETDATE() - 1
      AND vm.dtUTCDateTime < GETDATE())
      )Q
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working. By the way I didn't downvote your answer at first/

Comment: No worries bro there are some clowns out there doesnt bother me anyway :) anyway glad to help :)

Answer (score 5):

```
select iAssetId, max(fSpeedKPH)
from AssetsTable
group by iAssetId
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result. I am posting my SQL in the question hope you can help me.

Comment: @DawoodAwan . . . Try `group by vm.iAssetId`.  You don't want to group by the columns used in aggregation functions (except in some very rare circumstances).

Comment: If I don't add group by to the other columns the script doesn't execute

Comment: You shouldn't be grouping by vm.fSpeedKPH.